# Auto-Fading Out <%= notice %> and/or <%= alert %> flash messages

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Ok so I've followed a tutorial to make my rails flash alerts fade out using jQuery (first time integrating any jQuery in rails - I'm still a beginner).
I've added gem 'jquery-rails', required it in my application.js, and (for now) put these lines in my application.html.erb:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.notice-wrapper').fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $(this).remove();
      })
    }, 4500);
  });
</script>
```

The alerts display as they did, but they don't fade out. My inspector tells me:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

According to my research this can mean that the jquery is not loaded yet? so I tried putting the script in the head - no change. Does anyone have experience with this? Or is there an easier workaround?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? The 'jquery-rails' gem only works with the old spockets based assets pipeline. In Rails 6 with Webpacker you would install jQuery via Yarn instead of as a gem. You should also note that this will may only work on the initial page load if you're using Turbolinks.

Comment: Hey, thanks I didn't know that - just added it via yarn. Unfortunately it's still not working for me. I'll go try to find another tutorial to try out

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the reason it was not working is because I needed to adjust 2 lines in my environment.js. This is what I had by default:

```
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
$: 'jquery',
jQuery: 'jquery',
Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']  }));
```

After adjusting the lines containing 'jquery' to:

```
$: 'jquery/src/jquery',
jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
```

It all works.
Hopefully someone else finds this helpful. Have a great day!